# Как указать относительный путь к файлу, который лежит на уровень ниже?

Tags: html

Как указать относительный путь к файлу, который лежит на 1-2 уровня ниже?

На раб столе есть папка `site`.
В этой папке файл `Main.html` и папка `menu_5`.
В папке `menu_5` лежит файл `menu_5.html` и мне в этом файле надо указать путь к файлу `Main.html`. Как это сделать ?

Comment: А если на уровень ниже будет более одного каталога - который должен быть выбран?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил

1 уровень ниже - `<img src="folder/file.img">`

2 уровня ниже - `<img src="folder/folder2/file.img">`

По Вашему примеру:
`<a href="../Main.html">Link</a>`

Comment: А ничего, что ".." - каталог на один уровень ближе к корню?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и в чём проблема?

Comment: В том, что это ВЫШЕ на один-два уровня.

Comment: Это если у вас корень "сверху". В природе, к примеру, это не так

Comment: Аааа, все спасибо, я понял) дошло до меня

Answer (score 1):

если выше файлы то

```
../../file.html
```

если ниже то пишете

```
folder/folder/file.html
```

если в другой папке и там на 2 уровня ниже

```
../folder/folder/file.html
```

По вашему примеру

для `Main.html`

```
<a href="menu_5/menu_5.html">menu_5</a>
```

для `menu_5.html`

```
<a href="../Main.html">Main</a>
```

Comment: все спасибо, я понял) дошло до меня