# Ошибка в консоли: файл не найден

Tags: javascript, файлы

Не могу понять, что за ошибка в консоли. Вроде всё подключено верно. Что не так?

[image: console]
[image: file]
[image: src]

Comment: в ошибке же четко указано, что по указанному адресу нет файла. И судя по закрашенной папке на картинке, папка media действительно не расположена непосредственно внутри диска `C:`

Comment: Если вы начинаете путь со слеша, он воспринимается как абсолютный и поиск папки после слеша начинается с корня диска. Уберите слеш или поставьте перед ним точку как знак текущего каталога.

Comment: @Grundy я по проводнику сверил, там всё верно

Comment: @Alan, что именно верно? непосредственно в `C:` лежит папка `media` с нужными файлами? :-)

Comment: @Grundy вот полный путь C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Folder\media\js\main.js
Разве что-то неверно?

Comment: Конечно неверно. В ошибке тебе указан путь, по которому происходит поиск. И в нем явно нет части связанной с папкой рабочего стола пользователя

Comment: Возможно, вы неправильно указали относительный путь. Где лежит сам HTML? Может помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путь к файлу в `src` был абсолютный, от корня сайта, а сайта у вас вообще нет. Только папки на диске. Можно сделать путь относительным, но проблемы на этом не кончатся.

Система безопасности браузера работает для локального диска не так, как для сети (ошибка с `CORS`).

Запустите себе локально какой-нибудь сервер и отдавайте все файлы с него.

Например, `cd` вход в каталог, в котором находятся файлы и `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

Разрабатывать и проверять систему лучше в условиях приближенных к тем, в которых она в итоге будет работать.

Comment: если что не так -- пишите

Answer (score 2):

Файл не найден. Пропишите путь как `./media/js/main.js` точка со слэшем будет означать, что начало пути - корневая папка проекта.

Comment: Уже 2 ошибки


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/media/assets/particles/config.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.


GET file:///C:/media/assets/particles/config.json net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: @Alan здесь экстрасенсов нет, вставьте полностью код всех своих файлов, чтобы ответ получить...